# Saving data to MSSQL Db using XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have created a ASP.NET C# MVC application. I need to insert some records in the database, and the following code works fine. What i want to do now is to save records in the DB by using XML.

I found an example in a [tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2118/scripts-to-use-xml-to-insert-and-update-rows-in-a-sql-server-table/), but i am unable to modify my code send data to MSSQL via XML.

```
                using (SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PPL  (Name, Age) VALUES (@Name,@age)", c)){
                c.Open();
                c.ExecuteNonQuery();}
```

Can someone help me here ?

** The tutorial http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2118/scripts-to-use-xml-to-insert-and-update-rows-in-a-sql-server-table/

UPDATE

I created a SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_PPL

@NAME nchar(200),
@AGE nchar(3),

AS

INSERT INTO PPL(NAME,AGE)

VALUES (@NAME,@AGE)
```

Now i am suppose to use `EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @xmlData` add this line (according to the tutorial), but no clue how to edit it so it works in my program.

This is all what i have done.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: What i have tried has already been demonstrated above.

Comment: "the following code works fine"  ...  "but I am unable to modify my code to..." - so show us what modifications you have attempted.  Show us where you are stuck.  We're not going to do your work for you.

Comment: And please show us a sample of your XML.

Comment: I don't know if i got this right but, i am under the impression that i could generate XML from the stored procedure (I might be wrong) and insert it to the database.

Comment: Do you want to store actual XML in the database? Or you want to hand an XML document to the database and have it store the element values in the proper fields?

Comment: Yes i want to hand a XML document to the database and have it store the element values in the proper fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good approach is to serialize you classes to XML and pass them to SQL. For the server part, a path to begin with would be:

```
    create table Books (BookID int identity, Title varchar(50), Rating int);

    create table Chapters (BookID int, Title varchar(50), Sequence int);

    go

    create procedure AddBook
        @book xml
    as
    begin

        insert Books (Title, Rating)
        select
            n.value('@Title', 'varchar(50)'),
            n.value('@Rating', 'int')
        from
            @book.nodes('/Book') x(n);

        declare @bookID int;
        set @bookID = scope_identity();

        insert Chapters (BookID, Title, Sequence)
        select
            @bookID,
            n.value('@Title', 'varchar(50)'),
            n.value('@Sequence', 'int')
        from
            @book.nodes('/Book/Chapters/Chapter') x(n);

    end;

    go

    declare @data xml;
    set @data = '
    <Book Title="New Book" Rating="9">
        <Chapters>
            <Chapter Title="Chapter 1" Sequence="1" />
            <Chapter Title="Chapter 2" Sequence="2" />
            <Chapter Title="Chapter 3" Sequence="3" />
        </Chapters>
    </Book>'

    exec AddBook @data;

    select * from Books;
    select * from Chapters;
```

Result:

```
    BookID      Title                                              Rating
    ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
    1           New Book                                           9

    (1 row(s) affected)

    BookID      Title                                              Sequence
    ----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
    1           Chapter 1                                          1
    1           Chapter 2                                          2
    1           Chapter 3                                          3

    (3 row(s) affected)
```

And don't forget to pack the procedure statements in a transaction.